# Would magnesium react with acyl halides to form a variant of grignard reagent just like alkyl and aryl halides?

Tags: organic-chemistry, grignard-reagent

We were having a chemistry class in our school and we were discussing the answer to some question related to acyl halides when this popped up. Our teacher mused that it may be possible but he hadn't seen any source mention it ever. We all tried looking it up online but did not get anything. Does anyone have any information or arguments in support or opposition of this?

Comment: Welcome to ChemSE! Your question will likely be considered as homework and be voted down. You need to make some effort to answer the question yourself. Take a look here about homework policy. https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange. The lack of information may be telling you something. What would be the fate of such a "Grignard reagent" in solution during its formation? You might figure that Victor tried it. ;)

Comment: @OscarLanzi   Noted, comment deleted